# Put extensions in some logical groups, so that only extensions that have same group can call each other

Tags: sip, voip, freeswitch, fusionpbx

I need to use **FusionPBX** as **SIP registar** *(Session Initiation Protocol)* or **SIP server**, to route **SIP** calls to appropriate **SIP** accounts (extensions).

Currently every extension has possibility to call any registered extensions and everything works fine. But for my purposes I need to set some logic to enabling extensions to call only some group of extensions. My idea is to mark/put extensions in some kind of groups so that only extensions from same group can call each other.

Here is example:

Suppose that there are 4 extensions with numbers 101, 102, 103, 104 and 105.
Extension 101 is in groupA and groupB.
Extension 102 is in groupA.
Extension 103 is in groupB.
Extension 104 is in groupA.
Extension 105 is in groupC.

I need to set that:

- extension 101 can call and be called by all users from groupA and groupB, which means extensions 102, 103 and 104
- extension 102 can call and be called by all users from groupA, which means extensions 101 and 104
- extension 103 can call and be called by all users from groupB, which means extension 101.
- extension 104 can call and be called by all users from groupA, which means extensions 101 and 102
- extension 105 can call and be called by all users from groupC, which means nobody because there is no extension whit group C in current example

It is important to note that **extension can be in multiple groups** which means that it can call and accept calls from extensions from both groups. Also all extensions are internal.

Is it possible to achieve this scenario and how?

I tried setting extension's call group but that resulted with scenario where for example when I call extension in groupA all extensions from that group starts to ring which is not what I wanted.